# Karate DSL - Converting a PNG response to Base64

Tags: api, karate

I have a response from API 1 which is image/png - I am not able to paste the whole response here as it displays some junk characters after the PNG word -

```
--jetty829507547klm7mff0
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=document("+i+")

�PNG
```

I get a response from API 2 in base 64 and formatted. I need to convert the above in base 64 like this  -

```
{
  "account": null,
  "mimeContents": [
    {
      "base64String": "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",
      "imageSide": "0",
      "mimeContent": null
    }    
  ]
}
```

I am trying to do this to compare the 2 responses. How do I do this in Karate? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use java interop (search the docs) and the linked answer has some examples